# Draw reation in polyline - Android, osmdroid

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid, polyline

I'm using [osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid), and I would like to draw a relation: https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/2883357#map=13/49.7946/21.0785 in android app. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the points, you can use the [OSMBonusPack Polyline](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Features).

If you have to retrieve the geometry of the relation, you can use the OSMBonusPack [OverpassAPIProvider](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/OverpassAPIProvider) with urlForTagSearchKml method.

Comment: Is this really enough? Between retrieving and drawing the ways also might have to be sorted.

Comment: Call urlForTagSearchKml to build the url. Then call addInKmlFolder to perform the query. Each OSM relation will be converted to a KML MultiGeometry. This can be seen in action with OSMNavigator.